# Tcpdf multiCell border's missing when over gradient

Tags: php, tcpdf

How can you use MultiCell with a border over the gradient?

[image]

Note if you use Cell the border is displayed.

```
// set colors for gradients (r,g,b) or (grey 0-255)
$red = array(255, 0, 0);
$blue = array(0, 0, 200);
$yellow = array(255, 255, 0);
$green = array(0, 255, 0);
$white = array(255);
$black = array(0);

// set the coordinates x1,y1,x2,y2 of the gradient (see linear_gradient_coords.jpg)
$coords = array(0, 0, 1, 0);

// paint a linear gradient
$pdf->LinearGradient(20, 45, 80, 80, $red, $blue, $coords);

// write label
$pdf->MultiCell(100, 100, 'LinearGradient()', 1);
```

Comment: If you call `MultiCell` before `LinearGradient`, does it change anything?

Comment: The whole cell is displayed behind including the text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Nicola itself (https://sourceforge.net/p/tcpdf/bugs/236/) "this is wanted behaviour".

Add `$pdf->setPageMark()` between the gradient and the multicell.

```php
// paint a linear gradient
$pdf->LinearGradient(20, 45, 80, 80, $red, $blue, $coords);

$pdf->setPageMark();

// write label
$pdf->MultiCell(100, 100, 'LinearGradient()', 1);
```

Also, by `setPageMark` docblock:

> Set start-writing mark on current page stream used to put borders and fills. **Borders and fills are always created after content and inserted on the position marked by this method**. This function must be called after calling Image() function for a background image. Background images must be always inserted before calling Multicell() or WriteHTMLCell() or WriteHTML() functions.